# CloudFormation Launch configuration with encrypted boot volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template that created the required infrastructure to host a web application in my environment. This includes an AutoScaling group and Launch Configuration:

```
"LaunchConfiguration": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
            "Properties": {
                "AssociatePublicIpAddress": false,
                "IamInstanceProfile": {
                    "Ref": "InstanceRoleInstanceProfile"
                },
                "ImageId": {
                    "Ref": "WindowsImage"
                },
                "InstanceType": {
                    "Ref": "InstanceType"
                },
                "SecurityGroups": [
                    {
                        ...
                    }
                ],
                "KeyName": {
                    "Ref": "KeyPairName"
                },
                "UserData": {
                    ...
                },
                "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                    {
                        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                        "Ebs": {
                            "VolumeType": "gp2"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Metadata": {
                ...
            }
        }
```

A vulnerability scanner flagged a risk due to the boot volume of the instance coming out of the above launch configuration not being encrypted.

When I try to encrypt the boot volume by changing its configuration in the template as follows:

```
"BlockDeviceMappings": [
                        {
                            "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                            "Ebs": {
                                "Encrypted": true,
                                "VolumeType": "gp2"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
```

I get the following error:

> Launching a new EC2 instance. Status Reason: the encrypted flag cannot
>   be specified since device /dev/sda1 has a snapshot specified.
>   Launching EC2 instance failed.

I read you can encrypt boot volumes by

- spin up a server from the base AMI
- take a snapshot
- copy that snapshot with encryption
- create a custom AMI based on that copy of the snapshot
- then spin up new servers based on my encrypted AMI
- cleanup of all the servers, snapshots, and custom AMI created

I need CloudFormation to create EC2 instances that are already encrypted. Any idea if this is possible at all?